# Get files from SFTP folder filtered by suffix/extension with phpseclib nlist

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I need to get files from a SFTP server, but I only need the files with `txt` extension. It takes too much time if I loop the result and filter with PHP localy. How can I do that using `nlist`?

My code is:

```
$timeout_sftp = 30; 
$ls_directory = $sftp->nlist($sftp_path, false, $timeout_sftp);
```

Comment: i dont think any of php's ftp functions have file name filtering

Comment: Btw, I do not see `nlist` that would take three arguments in any version of phpseclib. https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.10/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFTP does not allow filtering of files (the protocol itself, it's not a limitation of SFTP implementation in PHP).

So all you can do is to retrieve listing of a whole directory and filter them locally.

```
$files = $sftp->nlist($sftp_path);

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (preg_match("/\.txt$/i", $file))
    {
        echo "Found $file\n";
    }
}
```

---

You can of course, use SSH "exec" channel to execute `ls *.txt` on the server. But that's not an SFTP solution anymore, you need to have a shell access to the server.

```
$filelist = $ssh->exec("ls *.txt");
```